# How to show the legend (scale colour) for points on a map?

Tags: r

version R 3.2.3

```
 library(OpenStreetMap)
 map <- openmap(c(lat= 48,   lon= 3),   c(lat= 40,   lon= 0))
 map <- openproj(map) 
 plot(map)
 lon=c(1, 03, 04, 08, -1)
  lat=c(40, 41, 41, 42, 41)
  x=c(1, 3, 0.1, 2, 1) #I give here example of only 5 values but my real values are many and vary. So the values here are not discrete but continuous!

 points(lon,lat,pch=19,col=x)  #not sure here how
```

I want to plot these points of x on the map with a color range from blue to red  and most importantly to show the scale color (legend) beside the map.

Answer (score 2):

In your question you've used `OpenStreetMap` (which I couldn't get to run); are you adverse to using `leaflet` instead?

If not you can do

```
library(leaflet)

df <- data.frame(lon=c(1, 03, 04, 08, -1),
                 lat=c(40, 41, 41, 42, 41),
                 x=c(1, 3, 0.1, 2, 1))

pal <- colorNumeric(
    palette = c("#ff0000","#0000ff"),
    domain = df$x
)

leaflet() %>%
    setView(lng = 3, lat = 48, zoom = 4) %>%
    addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldGrayCanvas") %>% ## pick any map layer you want
    addCircleMarkers(data = df, lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat, stroke=FALSE, color=~pal(x), fillOpacity = 0.6) %>%
    addLegend(position = c("bottomleft"), pal = pal, values = df$x)
```

[image]

Comment: @temor take a look at [leaflet for R](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/), and in particular the [legents](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/legends.html) page and the [raster image](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/raster.html) page

Comment: @temor looking at [the error message](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/master/R/colors.R) it suggests you have some `infinite` values in your range. What is `df$t[!is.finite(df$t)]` ?

Comment: I solved it because ""  but I still have problem with the size of legend

Comment: @temor I'm not so sure that's easily configurable